# How do I dynamically center div css height and width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have been trying to create somewhat of an image gallery, and I want the .lightboxCenter class to stay in the center of the page, but decrease in size for smaller screens. How would I go about doing this? Also when I resize the window the div covers the , how do I stop this from happening.
Many thanks.
https://jsfiddle.net/36jkh1hj/

```
.lightboxBackground {
  width:            100%;
  height:           100%;
  top:              0;
  left:             0;
  background-color: #000;
  opacity:          0.7;
  position:         fixed;
}

.lightboxCenter {
  position:         fixed;
  height:           400px;
  width:            600px;
  top:              50%;
  left:             50%;
  margin-top:       -200px;
  margin-left:      -300px;
  border-radius:    10px;
  background-color: black;
}

.closeLightbox {
  float:           right;
  margin-right:    20px;
  color:           #d3d3d3;
  font-size:       60px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family:     sans-serif;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your css something like this

```
.lightboxBackground {
width:100%;
height:100%;
top:0;
left:0;
background-color:#000;
opacity:.7;
position:fixed;
}

.lightboxCenter {
position:fixed;
height: calc(100% - 200px);
width: calc(100% - 200px);
top:100px;
left:100px;
margin-top:0;
margin-left:0px;
border-radius:10px;
background-color: black;
}

.closeLightbox {
float:right;
margin-right:20px;
color:#d3d3d3;
font-size:60px;
text-decoration:none;
font-family:sans-serif;
}
```

live demo : https://jsfiddle.net/36jkh1hj/1/

Answer (score 0):

I changed your `.lightboxCenter` to this ([jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/36jkh1hj/2/)):

```
.lightboxCenter {
    position:fixed;
    height:50%;
    width:50%;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    border-radius:10px;
    background-color: black;
}
```

Hope this helps you!

Answer (score 0):

## Here's a working JSFiddle

Simply change your CSS to this:

```
.lightboxCenter {
    /* - no need for these:
    position:fixed;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;*/

    /*height:400px; - this won't allow your box to resize*/
    height: 50vh; /*change this to whatever size you desire*/

    /*width:600px; - this won't allow your box to resize*/
    width: 50vw; /*change this to whatever size you desire*/

    /*margin-top:-200px;
    margin-left:-300px;*/
    margin: 10% auto; /* - to make sure the box is always centered*/

    border-radius:10px;
    background-color: black;
    /*added css:*/
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

lets see an example of how you can do this:
https://jsfiddle.net/rcheruti/36jkh1hj/3/

some changes to your code is required to get this behavior:

**1:** Group inside a `div` all the parts of the `lightbox`. In the exmaple, i create a `lightbox` class with the `Background`, `Center` and `close` tags inside. This is important to better control the elements, with this structure you can use `z-index` in the `CSS` to make the `X` button stay on top of the others elements (of the same DOM tree only).

**2:** Set the `width` and `height` of the `Center` to `100%`, and use `max-width` and `max-height` to limit to the size you want to be the max values. With this you will have the effect you want. If this doesnt work for you, then i think we will need to talk about `media querys` to solve this.

**3:** You can set the `Center` element to have `50%` on `left` and `top`. These two properties are calculated in relation to the parent relative element *(in the example, will be the `.lightbox` element because of the `position: fixed` CSS property on it)*.
With this the position is wrong, but we correct this with the `transform: translate(-50%, -50%)`. The transformation is calculated in relation to the size of the self element. This will position the element on the center of the screen.

**4:** Note that the properties of the `close` button need to change too. Now the button is `inline-block` and `absolute` positioned.

A diferente solution is to not use `max-` width and height, but to use `media querys` to set height and width for specific screen sizes, the common is to set width to `100%` under some sizes of screen.